# Is this the right way to display data from a table in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is the coding I tried to use to connect to my database in order to display some information to help me on my admin page. What did I do wrong?

Edit: When I load the page it was suppose to display the data from my tables, however the page is of course white.
[image: Code]

Comment: This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: "What did i do wrong" means that something is wrong and you have a message? or the output is just not to your liking? Please provide more info in order to be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct format is:

```
mysql_query($query, $resource)
```

You have it the other way round. Notwithstanding any other errors.

https://www.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: It's worth noting, OP, this isn't your fault, in PHP I once found that `shoot($gun,$foot)` created a "catchable fatal error" that took me ages to find, caused by $foot not being able to fire at my gun.

Comment: Okay so I changed the mysql_query around but it still displayed a blank page. I even took out the $dresult and everything after it to see if my php was fine and it worked great.

Comment: @TurnedTurquoise - missing ) on line #21. Other than that, you need to post your schema.

Comment: @TurnedTurquoise is `error_reporting` enabled with `display_error`?

Comment: @markdwhite That was all that I was missing. Needed to be more thorough next time.

Comment: @TurnedTurquoise - Get an IDE that highlights syntax errors :)